# IE 11 this page cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: nginx, iframe, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

There is a iframe tag whose src (N page) is not same origin in a WordPress page.

1. I have checked that N page's http header includes 
   `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM *.mydomain.com;`
   `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *.mydomain.com`
   `X-XSS-protection: 0`
   which are totally ovewrited by proxy_hide_header and `Set-Cookie` header is hided by proxy_hide_header, too.
2. But it's still not working in IE 11 but working in chrome or safari.

I don't know why..

Comment: ALLOW-FROM must be URI, not a wildcard

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for @Alexey Ten

X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM needs `URI` format.

I tested and it works in IE11,10,9 & 8.

My nginx.conf has only

```
proxy_hide_header 'X-Frame-Options'; # this should be needed
add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM http://sub.example.com';
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'frame-ancestors http://sub.example.com';
```